# AORUS x570, turn off lights on shutdown

Tags: 22.04, shutdown, motherboard, peripherals

I recently upgraded my motherboard and I am finding an annoying issue I never had before.

When I power off the computer all my peripherals and the rgb RAM remain on. I sleep in the same room as my computer and this is terrible to sleep around so I end up having to press the power switch on the PSU to make sure it's off.

This did not happen with my old motherbaord. What do i need to do to make sure all lights are off when i shut down the computer?

Comment: This is a hardware problem not an Ubuntu problem. Maybe USB power mode in BIOS?

Comment: I don't seem to have a power mode on my bios.